# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm still super new to coding! Trying to learn from online tutorials, but I seem to be stuck on the first step! I think I installed bs4, but it's not showing up in python3, is it installed in the wrong place?

```
robbie$ sudo -H pip install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from bs4)
Robbies-MBP:~ robbie$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: run on **python** not **python3** because u install bs4 in `python2.7`

Answer (score 18):

> Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /Library/**Python/2.7**/site-packages
>
> **Python 3.6.1** (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04)

You have the module installed for Python 2.7, however you're using and trying to `import` it with Python 3.6.

You have to use `pip3` like you use `python3`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried using 'pip3', and now it works beautifully!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **python 3** then you shoud use pip 3. In order to install it in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

And then use the following command for installing the module bs4:

```
pip3 install bs4
```

Answer (score 4):

go to the bottom left of your vs code and select python 3.9.1 64 bit (depending on the version of your python). it'll work.

it works for me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note but a lot of times when this happens and you are running python3 and you used pip3 to install bs4 or another module but are running two different versions of python3 (eg 3.4 and 3.6). Sometimes just doing a normal update in a distro like CentOS installs a newer version of python, but not the corresponding pip.

Take for example here where a user is running python3.6 but all modules are installed only for python3.4 and there is no pip3.6 available.

http://realtechtalk.com/python_ModuleNotFoundError_No_module_named_bs4_even_though_you_have_the_module-2267-articles

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but managed to solve it with custom install script in the code. This tries to import and if it fails, automatically installs it

```
def safe_import(module):
    try:
        exec(f'import {module}')
        globals()[module] = eval(module)
    except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
        import os
        os.system(f'pip install {module}')
        exec(f'import {module}')
        globals()[module] =  eval(module)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33035188)